# How can I avoid single quotation marks from my string

Tags: c#, asp.net

This the sample data I am trying to remove single quotes (`'`) from:

```
string address="Unnamed Road, Kemerovskaya oblast', Russia, 652226 ";
```

I just want to remove single quotation mark from the string, for example

```
string resultString="Unnamed Road, Kemerovskaya oblast, Russia, 652226 ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replace method,

```
string address="Unnamed Road, Kemerovskaya oblast', Russia, 652226 ";

resultString = address.Replace("'",string.Empty);
```

**OR**

```
resultString = address.Replace("'","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **Replace**

```
string address="Unnamed Road, Kemerovskaya oblast', Russia, 652226 ";

address = address.Replace("'",string.Empty);
```

or

```
address = address.Replace(@"'",string.Empty);
```

if you dont want to go for escape sequences to be  recognized go for **verbatim**  like this `@"..."`